# Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Leap.Hand>` to `Leap.Hand`

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I've got this error
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Leap.Hand>` to `Leap.Hand`

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Leap;
using Leap.Unity;

public class Swimming : MonoBehaviour {

    Controller controller;


    void Start(){
        controller = new Controller ();
    }

    void Update(){

        Frame frame =  controller.Frame (); // controller is a Controller object
        Hand hand = frame.Hands;

        for (int i = 0; i < frame.Hands.Count; i++) {
            if (frame.Hands [i].IsLeft) {
                Debug.Log ("Left Hand Detected");
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I've searched a lot but i couldn't find something. Can anyone help me please

Comment: `frame.Hands` is a collection of `Hand` instances. It is not a single `Hand`. It is a thing which contains many `Hand`s. That is a different thing. A box containing kittens is not a kitten. You cannot feed the box. If you want one kitten, you must reach in and take one kitten out. That is the kitten. The box is not the kitten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Hand hand = frame.Hands;
```

`frame.Hands` is a collection of `Hand`, but you're trying to assign this value to a single instance of `Hand`. So, instead, you should be doing this:

```
List<Hand> hands = frame.Hands;
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir . So does my code can detect if the hand is right / is left?

Comment: Well actually, your code looks fine even without this collection of hands. Not sure why you're assigning this variable at all, really.

Comment: base on what i understand the for loop is for the finger count. so if the hand is left it'll debug.log(Left hand detected);